# Kibana: How can we create visualisation for each value in a column?

Tags: elasticsearch, canvas, kibana, visualization, bucket

I have an index in elasticsearch which contains heartbeat data coming from different machines in the following format:
**Machine Name**                   **Heartbeat Signal Time**
host_1                              2023-01-11 15:00
host_2                              2023-01-11 15:07
host_1                              2023-01-11 15:15
host_3                              2023-01-11 15:19
....                                 ....

So I want to create a visualisation for each unique value in the machine name column with value 1 on y-axis (depicting count of heartbeat signal sent at a particular time for a machine) and time range on x-axis.
In other words, I want to create a time range histogram for each machine when it was online/offline.

Is there a way to automate it or do I need to create visualisation for each unique entry in machine as the new value is added?

I tried creating buckets, canvas and all tools given in Kibana but was not able to get the required visualisations.

Comment: Your question is quite ambiguous, on one hand you are saying is there a way to automate and on the other you want to create a visualization. What exactly do you want to automate here ? Date Histogram is a visualization capable enough for your use case, but it can only be automated if you have a NDJSON formatted export of that visualization for one machine. Create a template our of export and import using automata by replacing placeholders (of machine names) with actual values.

I have done this for whole lot of dashboards and works like a charm.

Comment: Hi Ayush
What API endpoint are you using to post the data for new visualisation?

Comment: Use saved_object API to import or export the objects, you need to always refer the Elastic documentation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/saved-objects-api-import.html